# Integration application to volume

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

I'm trying to find out the volume of:
Area enclosed by $y=\arctan x, \ y=0, \ x=1$ rotated about y-axis.
I tried to use both the disc and cylindrical method, and I can get it with the cylindrical shell method, but not with the disc method. Here's my cylindrical shell solution:
$$
2\pi rh\delta t=2\pi x\arctan x\delta x \\ 
\int^1_0 2\pi x\arctan xdx=\pi(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)
$$
And here's my attempt at a disc solution:
Inner shell$$
\pi r^2\delta h=\pi x^2\delta y=\pi(1-\tan y)^2\delta y \\ 
\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0{\pi(1-tany)^2)}
$$Outer shell$$
\pi r^2 \delta h=\pi1^2\delta h \\ 
\pi\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0{1}dy
$$However,$$
\pi\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0{1}dy-\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0{\pi(1-tany)^2)}\neq\pi(\frac{\pi}{2}-1)
$$Could someone help me pick out where I have gone wrong? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your working for the cylindrical shell method is correct. In disk method, you have a mistake in the volume integral for the inner shell.

It should be $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} \pi x^2 \ dy = \int_0^{\pi/4} \pi  \ \color {blue} {(\tan y)}^2  \ dy = \frac{\pi}{4}(4-\pi) \ $.

So the volume using disk method $ = \displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{4} -  \frac{\pi}{4}(4-\pi) = \pi (\frac{\pi}{2}-1)$

Comment: Thank you! I think I mistakenly thought I was still integrating w.r.t to x when I was doing it w.r.t to y, so I shouldn't have taken the area between 1 and tany, but just between tany and 0.